# Calculating nanocluster's Lewis acidity

Tags: acid-base, computational-chemistry, nanotechnology

In general, fluoride ion affinity, ammonia binding energy, photoacoustic IR spectra of adsorbed species (pyridine, CO) are used to measure the Lewis acidity of a material.

But in the **computer simulation method**, such methods are not suitable to calculate nanoclusters Lewis acidity because of the susceptible electronic environment of the system

```
[if extra species placed near a nanocluster, nanoclusters change their configuration and 
form chemisorption as nanoclusters are unstable (tend to form bigger species: nucleation. 
Furthermore, it might be a global minimum (GM)].
```

Thus, I concluded that calculating **electron affinity (EA)** might be the most suitable method to calculate the Lewis acidity of nanoclusters (*overall, not for each cation/active site*).

What do you think about the method to calculate the Lewis acidity for the nanoclusters system?
or is there a method to calculate the Lewis acidity of each atom site for the nanoclusters system?